# Passing array value from one class to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to ReactJs and the issue that I am having is that the array value is not being displayed on the body

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let arr = ["one", "two"]
    arr.map(n => <Append val={n}/>)

    return
       <div></div>
  }
}

class Append extends React.Component{
  render(){

    return(
     <div>
        {this.props.val}
      </div>
     )

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("div"))
```

My goal is to append to the body the two array values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the div is empty and you are not displaying the result of the map within the div. So that is why you're not seeing anything. One solution is to map append within div. Also, if you want to display the div in the next line, make sure to wrap it in a parenthesis. Otherwise, it will print undefined and ignore the intended return value (the div etc).

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let arr = ["one", "two"]
    return (
       <div>{arr.map(n => <Append val={n}/>)}</div>
    );
  }
}

class Append extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
     <div>
        {this.props.val}
      </div>
     );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("div"))
```

Comment: I am getting Uncaught Error: Minified React error #37;

Comment: Do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

You've got two issues here:

## 1

The elements you're creating with `map` need to be moved *inside* the `<div>` you're returning.

This expression

```
arr.map(n => <Append val={n}/>)
```

as a statement has no effect on its own. The `map` converts a list of strings into a list of `<Append>` elements, but it doesn't *do* anything with them.

## 2

`return` and `<div>` need to be on the same line, or you need parentheses like you did in the other `render` function.

When you write this,

```
return
   <div></div>
```

[automatic semi-colon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) takes place, and what actually runs is this:

```
return;
   <div></div>
```

So what you're returning is `undefined`, not the `<div>` element you wanted.

---

So the fixed `App` class looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let arr = ["one", "two"];
    return <div>{arr.map(n => <Append val={n}/>)}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting Uncaught Error: Minified React error #37;

Answer (score 1):

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let arr = ["one", "two"];
   // arr.map(n => <Append val={n}/>); 
    let appendValues = arr.map(n => <Append val={n}/>);

    return
       <div>{appendValues}</div>
  }
}

class Append extends React.Component{
  render(){

    return(
     <div>
        {this.props.val}
      </div>
     )

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("div"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let arr = ["one", "two"];
    let numbers = [];
    
    arr.map(n => numbers.push(<Append val={n} key={n} />));

    return (
       <div>{numbers}</div>
    );
  }
}

class Append extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
     <div>
        {this.props.val}
      </div>
     );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("div"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: I am getting Uncaught Error: Minified React error #37;

Comment: @AvaLucas Do you use the minified versions of React and ReactDOM?

Comment: @AvaLucas That's the reason. Did you check the error message?

Comment: yes just like i said earlier it says Uncaught Error: Minified React error #37;

Answer (score 1):

As have an extra look at the document.getElementById functions, it looks like your not giving it a correct id for a element on the page but rather the name of a div element.

Then have a look at the array.map, .map returns a new array so your App component needs to render that array inside of the element it returns.

I made a small video about your question and I added some small tips if you are interested: https://youtu.be/I9U8I1Yn4c4

Look at this code to get some ideas and have a great day!

```
const React = require("react");
const ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let arr = ["one", "two"];
    return <ul>{arr.map(n => <Append key={n} val={n} />)}</ul>;
  }
}

class Append extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        {this.props.val}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("content"));
```

Comment: I am getting Uncaught Error: Minified React error #37;